# Is there any magic method for reflected augmented assignment?

Tags: python, oop, methods, operator-overloading, magic-methods

I have two user-defined classes, `a` and `b`. For such an augmented addition assignment between them:

```
a += b
```

Where `a` returns `NotImplemented` when it encounters `b`, is it expected that Python will look for a reflected augmented assignment in the other operand, i.e. `b`?

(Edited in response to comments)

I have noticed that already a slightly similar concept exists in some other magic methods, like `__format__(self, other)`:

```
"A string {var:fmt_str}".format(var=b) === b.__format__("fmt_str")
```

Comment: Reflected `__iadd__` wouldn't make sense, because then you would effectively be assigning to the right-hand side. It goes `a += b` -> `a = a + b` -> `a = b + a` -> `TypeError`. See the docs: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__iadd__.

Comment: @jonrsharpe: It wouldn't have to assign to the right-hand side. There are potential use cases for `a += b` trying something like `a = b.__riadd__(a)`, where `b.__riadd__` attempts to mutate `a`.

Comment: (Also, the operation does not try `a = b + a`, because Python doesn't assume addition is commutative for arbitrary operands. When the `+=` operation delegates to `b`, it does so in a different way from `a = b + a`.)

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica I mean more _conceptually_ - a + b flips to to b + a, so how does a += b flip, b += a?

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica (the data model docs say `__radd__` _is_ considered)

Comment: @jonrsharpe: `a + b` *doesn't* flip to `b + a`. It uses a distinct `__radd__` hook, to avoid breaking non-commutative addition operators. `b.__radd__(a)` is very different from `b + a`. Similarly, a hypothetical `b.__riadd__(a)` would do something very different from `b += a`.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica yes, I'm aware of radd. I think we're talking at cross purposes.

Comment: @jonrsharpe: Perhaps. Consider `a - b`. When Python tries the reflected hook, it's definitely not trying `b - a`. A reflected hook is very different from flipping the operand order - it's the same operation, in the original operand order, just letting the RHS operand handle it. Similarly, a reflected hook for `a -= b` wouldn't mean `b -= a`. It would be the same `a -= b` operation, just letting `b` define what the operation means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope. No reflected augmented assignment hooks. If `__iadd__` fails, this operation falls back to `__add__` and `__radd__`.

You can check the big list of numeric operator hooks in the [data model docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#emulating-numeric-types) to verify that there aren't any reflected augmented assignment hooks there.